# forcing jquery ui datepicker to close / not popup

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a jquery ui datepicker in a dialog and I noticed when I close the dialog it sometimes sticks around.

I tried to  do

```
 $('#ui-datepicker-div').hide();
```

but that does not seem to hide it all.

I see there is a dialog option but I have no clue if that is what I need or how to use it

> dialog
>
> ```
> .datepicker( "dialog" , date , [onSelect] , [settings] , [pos] )
> ```
>
> Open a datepicker in a "dialog" box.
>
> dateText: the initial date for the
>   date picker as either a Date or a
>   string in the current date format.
>
> onSelect: A callback function when a
>   date is selected. The function
>   receives the date text and date picker
>   instance as parameters.
>
> settings: The new settings for the
>   date picker.
>
> pos: The position of the top/left of
>   the dialog as [x, y] or a MouseEvent
>   that contains the coordinates. If not
>   specified the dialog is centered on
>   the screen.

Also sometimes when I open the dialog the datepicker opens up and is in like the left hand corner of my screen under the dialog.

I believe that is because I populate a default value but I do it through the datepicker so I am not sure why it is poping up sometimes and sometimes it does not

```
  $('#datepicker').datepicker("setDate", '+1d')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its better to use `.remove()` instead of `.hide()` in scenarios where you are crating new instances.

Or better way: Use datepicker's method like `.datepicker("hide")` .. you can see it at [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#method-hide).

Comment: You need to add a blur as well 


$('#txtDate').datepicker("hide"); 

$('#txtDate').blur();

Answer (score 0):

You can also implement this using css. It is not the optimal way of doing it, but it surely does the job for you.

> > ```
> > $('#datepicker').css('visibility','hidden');
> > ```